# Issue with VBA Access Listbox selection while changing the row source trigger multiple times

Tags: ms-access

Please help!
I have a form which looks like this. Based on Task ID the List box gets updated. I have a query to update the list. All items should be selected and the right-side text box should have all these separated by coma. SEE IMAGE1
 [image]
It works well when I open the form first time and select any Task ID. But if I change the ID couple of times then the selection is wired, and the text box has extra comas. SEE IMAGE2
 [image]

Below are the codes can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
Private Sub TaskIDBox_AfterUpdate()

'Update automation

Dim r As Integer

Me.AutoLean.Requery

'Select All

For r = 0 To Me.AutoLean.ListCount() - 1

Me.AutoLean.Selected(r) = True

Next r

'Selected Automation

Call subs.SelectedAutoLean("Input Form")

End Sub
```

```
Public Sub SelectedAutoLean(FormName)

'Update Selected Automation

Dim sTemp As String

Dim oItem As Variant

Dim iCount As Integer

'AutoLean List

sTemp = ""

iCount = 0

If Forms(FormName)!AutoLean.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then

For Each oItem In Forms(FormName)!AutoLean.ItemsSelected

        If iCount = 0 Then

            sTemp = sTemp & Forms(FormName)!AutoLean.ItemData(oItem)

                iCount = iCount + 1

        Else

            sTemp = sTemp & "," & Forms(FormName)!AutoLean.ItemData(oItem)

                iCount = iCount + 1

        End If

        Next oItem

End If

Forms(FormName)!SelectedAutoLean.Value = sTemp

End sub
```

Comment: To add some more insights the list can increase or decrease based on taks ID. Example 3001 task has 16 items. So when I change 3003 to 3001 to 3002 couple of times then the error is coming up.

Answer (score 0):

As a short term solution I have come up with a code like below. This has reduced the efficiency. So looking for someone's help.

```
    Public Sub CloseAndReopenInputForm()
    Dim sID As Integer
    sID = Forms("Input Form").TaskIDBox.Value
    DoCmd.close
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Input Form", acNormal
    Forms("Input Form").TaskIDBox.Value = sID

    'Update automation
    Dim r As Integer
    Forms("Input Form").AutoLean.Requery

    'Select All
    For r = 0 To Forms("Input Form").AutoLean.ListCount() - 1
    Forms("Input Form").AutoLean.Selected(r) = True
    Next r

    'Selected Automation
    Call subs.SelectedAutoLean("Input Form")

    End Sub
```